# Parameter to Apex method is going null in Lightning Javascript

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am trying to pass recordid to apex method, but its going null everytime. below is my code. Kindly advise.

```
 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.validate }"/>

 <aura:attribute name="message" type="String"/>
 <aura:attribute name="appid" type="String" default="{!v.recordId}" access="global" /> 
 <aura:attribute name="result"  type="String" default="Go"/>
 <aura:attribute name="result2"  type="String" default="No"/>

  <!--  <ui:button label="GO" press="{!c.validate}"/>-->

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.message==v.result}">
           <div> 
                   <p>Display Message 1</p>
           </div> 
</aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.message==v.result2}">
           <div> 
                   <p>Display Message 2</p>
           </div> 
</aura:if>    
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.message}">
           <div> 
                   <p>Display Message 3</p>
           </div> 
</aura:if>
```

Here is the Javascript of this component:

({

```
validate:function(cmp, evt, helper) {
     //var appid = cmp.get("v.recordid");

    var action = cmp.get("c.GetScreeningResult");
    action.setParams({ "appid" : cmp.get("v.recordid") });


    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        cmp.set("v.message", a.getReturnValue());
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

HideMe: function(component, event, helper) {
  component.set("v.ShowModule", false);
```

},

})

Here is the apex method.

```
public class Getscreening {
@AuraEnabled
public static String GetScreeningResult(string appid){

string result = 'No';
system.debug('Application id is = '+appid );
list<application__c> id = [select id from application__c where id = :appid ];
string appqueryresults = String.valueOf(id[0]);
system.debug('appqueryresults' + appqueryresults );
    return appqueryresults ;

}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recordid` is not correct. It should be `recordId`. Javascript attributes are case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you @salesforcesas, that was very silly from my end :)